# Can RANK function be used anywhere other than the WITH clause

Tags: mdx

In a previous post I had this script:

```
WITH 
SET [orderedSet] AS
    ORDER(
    [Operator].members,
    [Operator].currentmember.name,
    BASC
    )
MEMBER [Measures].[newMeasure] AS
    RANK(
    [Operator].currentmember, 
    [orderedSet]
    )
SELECT
   [Measures].[newMeasure] ON COLUMNS,
   [orderedSet] ON ROWS
FROM [ourCube]
```

Plus further reference to the [**MSDN page**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144726.aspx)

Can the `RANK` function be used in any clauses other than `WITH`?

It's first argument is a tuple so I'm not sure how to use it in other clauses such as the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be used anywhere where a numeric expression can be used.

Please note that in MDX, the axes in the select clause are sets, hence you cannot use Rank or any function that returns a numeric expression in an axis clause, but only functions returning sets (or some data types like tuples which are implicitly converted to sets).
And all members that appear in an expression returning a set have to be defined before you start with this expression. Hence, you cannot define them in the axis clause like you can use expressions to define result columns in SQL selects.

However, to literally answer your question, you can use `Rank` indirectly in the select clause in MDX e. g. if the outer function is `Filter`, which returns a set. The following is a slightly inefficient way to show the first three countries according to attribute order:

```
SELECT {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]}
       ON COLUMNS,
       Filter(
             [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].Members as C,
             Rank(C.Current, [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].Members) <= 3
             )
       ON ROWS
  FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Some people use `Rank` within `Generate` to reverse sets, which would be another use of Rank that would be legal in the select clause.

Comment: +1 excellent information - thanks Frank. Like the use of `alias` `C`...not something I've seen before but it seems to make `filter` more readable.

Comment: @whytheq You need these aliases in functions like `Filter` or `Generate` if you need to reference the current value of the iteration. This can be omitted in some cases, and just come from context, but `Rank` needs a first argument that is non empty, hence you need to use the alias.